# Verilog Syntax unable to understand

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Can someone please help me to understand what `` #(.LENGTH(`REG_FILE_ADDR_LEN)) `` in the following code means? Also, will this code be synthesizable?

Lets say we have defined `REG_FILE_ADDR_LEN = 32.`

```
mux #(.LENGTH(`REG_FILE_ADDR_LEN)) mux_src2 (
    .in1(instruction[15:11]),
    .in2(instruction[25:21]),
    .sel(ST_or_BNE),
    .out(src2_reg_file)
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining a module, you can define parameters, for example:

```
module mux #(
    parameter LENGTH = <some default value>
)
(
    /** ports **/
);
    /** implementation **/

endmodule;
```

When instantiating that module, you can override the default parameter. In your case, you would override `LENGTH` with 32. You can use a parameter, for example, in a port or local variable of that module.

Yes. It is synthesizable.